# In what situation ‘that’s fine’ is an appropriate answer to the question?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I often get confused with the reply ‘ that’s fine’.I exactly don’t know the situations that the answer is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You would respond to a question with "That's fine" when the question is about whether something is correct or acceptable.  It's basically a way of saying that the speaker has no problem with what the questioner is asking about.

For example, you might respond with "That's fine" to any of these:

> Would you like us to schedule a taxi for you for tomorrow morning?
>   I got Terry some new shoes for her birthday; do you think that's OK?
>   I'm sorry, but the earliest that Dr. Chandra can see you is 11 AM tomorrow; do you still want to make that appointment?

Comment: If the speaker has a problem with the questioner at that time what would be the reply please?

Comment: It depends on what the question was.  It might be something like "No thanks" or "Unfortunately not".